# Equivariant spectrum with coefficients

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, equivariant-homotopy

I am curious to know whether spectra with coefficients as defined in Adams's Blue book be defined to an equivariant setting. In the non-equivariant case, for a spectrum $E$ and an abelian group $A$, one can define the spectrum with coefficients in $A$ by taking the smash product $E\wedge M(A)$, where $M(A)$ is the Moore spectrum.

How can I define a $G$-equivariant spectrum with coefficients?

Comment: Do you want $G$ go act on $A$? In that case there are obstructions, cf. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2154066

Comment: No, I want to see whether the generalisation of spectrum with coefficients is possible in the equivariant case. I am curious whether there is such a thing as an equivariant spectrum with coefficients.

Comment: This was asked at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431226/equivariant-spectra-with-coefficients and answered in the comments.  The category of $G$-equivariant spectra (like any stable $\infty$-category) is enriched over the category of spectra, so you can just define $EA=E\wedge M(A)$ again.